# Jquery slide toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am trying to create a slide toggle for my web. I have copied code from another source but it does not seem to work. I have src jquery ui and jquery. But it is not working. Any suggestions?

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var contactHidden = false;
    $(".contactHider").click(function(){
        var effect = 'slide';
        var opt = { direction: 'right' };
        var duration = 700;
        $('.contactDiv').toggle(effect, opt, duration);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.contactDiv { 
height: 100%;
width: 300px;
background-color: #414040;
float:right;
right:0;
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
}

.contactHider{
    height:100%;
    background:#999;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:20px;
    font-weight:700;
    font-family:OpenSansBold;
    float:right;
    margin-right:300px;
    z-index:1335;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: try giving it by id #

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: And otherwise the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle by class, use the below code and ajust it according to your requirement. Put the area under div which you want to toggle.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

$(function() {
   $( "#DivID" ).click(function() {
  $( "#effect" ).toggleClass( ".className", 1000 );
  });
```

});

Comment: @Manwal: class may be used somewhere else also, so it may conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Manwal. But I am trying to animate the toggle to slide right. If it is a normal toggle or toggleClass it works fine, but no sliding animation. Is there a way to make the slideToggle?

Comment: I added and id and tried to use that instead, but no luck

Comment: @RickyHalim: can you show your code, what you applied. and also check my edited code. Also, give us some more information where are u using these classes in the html ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside head tag if you create link for your jquery file before`<script type="text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. then your file may be processed before jquery. so keep link of your file after `<script type="text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Another common mistake is a closing `</script>` tag. If the link would not be closed then some browsers enclose rest part inside `<script>` tag.
for code `$(document).ready(function() {
          //if you want you can use [$('.contactDiv').slideToggle("fast");] but don't hide it in any other way.
          $(".contactHider").click(function(){
          $('.contactDiv').slideToggle("slow");
          });
          });`

Comment: u can use: $(function() {
   $( "#DivID" ).click(function() {
  $( "#effect" ).toggleClass( ".className", 1000 );
  });